# Hosts in vlan cannot access internet

Tags: router, switching, vlan

I just configured my L3 swich with vlan, and inter vlan communication is fine, but none of the hosts inside vlans can access internet. Here is my configuration

On switch:

```
vlan 10  - 1/0/1 - 10.0.10.1/24
vlan 20  - 1/0/2 - 10.0.20.1/24
vlan 100 - 1/0/3 - 192.168.0.87/24
```

```
10.0.10.0    255.255.255.0  10.0.10.1     vlan10
10.0.20.0    255.255.255.0  10.0.20.1     vlan20
192.168.0.0  255.255.255.0  192.168.0.87  vlan100
0.0.0.0      0.0.0.0        192.168.0.1   vlan100
```

On router:

```
10.0.0.0     255.255.0.0    192.168.0.87  lan0
0.0.0.0      0.0.0.0        WAN_ADDR      wan0
```

And port 1/0/3(switch) is connected to lan0(router)

I can ping 10.0.10.2 without problem using 192.168.0.25, gateway 192.168.0.1, but hosts in vlan20 and vlan10 cannot access internet

hardware:

```
switch - NETGEAR GS108Tv3
router - TPLINK  AX1500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking port 1/0/3(switch) of GS108Tv3 if it is tagged (T) and PVID is set to PVID 1. This should allow internet access.